# How to insert multiple images based on a condition in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, file-upload

I have created a page which takes multiple images and upload it to a database. Now, I've to create an edit page for this insert page, where all the uploaded images will be shown in multiple image field and at the same time I've provided a file-upload field just beside each image field in order to update that particular image.

Now my question is, if user wants to update a particular image, user will upload an another image to the file-upload which is placed beside that image(updating image) and leave all other images unchanged. Then how can I check and take image from image field if there is no file in file-upload else take image from file-upload.

Since, I've more than 30 images to be taken care of like this, then how can I do all this checking for each image field and file-upload and take the appropriate value and insert using insert statement.

Below is the design code of a small part:

```
<table style="width:100%;">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" style="border: thin solid #808080"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">After Site Solarisation, any ATC material/equipments
                                <br />
                                lying idle at Site? (Ex:- Power Plant, Battery Bank, etc)</span></td>
                            <td colspan="4" style="border: thin solid #808080">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdle" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="6" style="border: thin solid #808080"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">If Yes, List out the equipments with quantity (photographs to be attached).</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080;">&nbsp;</td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080;">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA;mso-bidi-font-weight:bold">ITEMS</span></td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">UOM</span></td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">QTY</span></td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center"><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">PHOTOS</span></td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; "><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">UPDATE PHOTOS</span></td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; "><span style="font-size:11.0pt;font-family:&quot;Trebuchet MS&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;
mso-fareast-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-font-family:Calibri;mso-bidi-theme-font:
minor-latin;mso-ansi-language:EN-US;mso-fareast-language:EN-US;mso-bidi-language:
AR-SA">REMARKS</span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelItems1" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelUOM1" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelQty1" runat="server" Height="25px" TextMode="Number" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:Image ID="ImgIdel1" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIdelPhoto1" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelRemarks1" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="196px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelItems2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelUOM2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelQty2" runat="server" Height="25px" TextMode="Number" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:Image ID="ImgIdel2" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIdelPhoto2" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelRemarks2" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="196px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelItems3" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelUOM3" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelQty3" runat="server" Height="25px" TextMode="Number" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:Image ID="ImgIdel3" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIdelPhoto3" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelRemarks3" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="196px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelItems4" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelUOM4" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelQty4" runat="server" Height="25px" TextMode="Number" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:Image ID="ImgIdel4" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIdelPhoto4" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelRemarks4" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="196px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelItems5" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="254px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelUOM5" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="169px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelQty5" runat="server" Height="25px" TextMode="Number" Width="103px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center;">
                                <asp:Image ID="ImgIdel5" runat="server" Height="100px" Width="100px" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuIdelPhoto5" runat="server" />
                            </td>
                            <td style="border: thin solid #808080; text-align: center; ">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIdelRemarks5" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="196px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

Please help, totally confused, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have  any `id` or primary key  field for images in database?

Comment: and post some code at least your design and some code.

Comment: @yogi970 Yes I've a version number for each insertion and I've updated my question too. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can use session to keep track of the images uploaded to the server. 
For example when every you new file has been update to the record the Datetime of the upload for that particular image. For instance you can do something on your image load function.

```
    Dictionary<string,DateTime> ImageUploadDictionary = new Dictionary<string,DateTime>();
```

When ever there is new update to the image folder. Do something like 
        ImageUploadDictionary.add ("ImageName", DateTime.Now);

Store the dictionary in the session and thus you can access the latest one on form submission. I am not too sure whether that answers your questions :)

Comment: I'm very sorry to tell you, this is not what I want. My question is "how can I check and take image from image field if there is no file in file-upload else take image from file-upload."

Comment: You can do something like this in your code behind:
    if (fuIdelPhoto2.HasFile)
to see if there is a file in the file-upload field and it will return true if the file exists else you can check the image fields for the path.

Comment: yeah if there was only one image I could have done like that, but there are more than 30 for now and I've to insert all this at a time in one insert statement, so that it will store in one row under one id. Hope you understand